# Understanding the conditional in a specific case

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

The problem given was as follows:

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a surjective function. Let us define a relation on A by setting $a_0$ ~ $a_1$ if $f(a_0) = f(a_1)$

Does this definition mean that $[f(a_0) = f(a_1)] => [a_0 $ ~ $a_1]$ or the inverse? This would be my first approach since the truth of the second statement depends on the truth of the first.

But then again if we have the inverse $[a_0 $ ~ $a_1] => [f(a_0) = f(a_1)]$, this also makes sense since it would be false for the relation to hold and the function values to be equal.

Comment: My thinking about this: If something is **defined** and in that definition the term *if* is used than you are allowed to read it as *if and only if*. Sufficient conditions are not enough to make it a real definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an equivalence between the relation and its definition.   That is a biconditional connection: $$a_0\sim a_1 \quad\iff\quad f(a_0)=f(a_1)$$